# How can I typeset the following symbol for beep in multimeter (code)?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I typeset the following symbol for beep in multimeter?[image]

Comment: Is the RSS icon enough? You can rotate it. http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/rss/

Comment: A multimeter? Do you need this done in Latex?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is the same as [Sigur's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245553/how-can-i-typeset-the-following-symbol-for-beep-in-multimeter-code#comment583777_245553), to rotate a symbol from the FontAwesome font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\fawesome{FontAwesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand{\beep}{{\fawesome\raisebox{.75ex}{\rotatebox[origin=bl]{320}{\char"F09E}}}}

\begin{document}
Will the symbol \beep do?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just need some circular waves, you may want to use `expanding waves` here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{radiation/.style={decorate,decoration={expanding waves,segment length=3pt},thick}}

\begin{document}
Beep: \tikz[baseline=-.5ex]{\draw[radiation,decoration={angle=30}] (0,0) -- (.5,0);} 
\end{document}
```

[image]